# how to check if a particular xml tag is present or not in ftl file

Tags: java, xml, freemarker

I have an XML file which looks like below.

```
<GetInventoryBalance
    xmlns="http://collab.safeway.com/it/architecture/info/default.aspx">
    <InventoryBalanceData>
        <AvailableQty>10.0000</AvailableQty>
        <AllocatedQty>57.0000</AllocatedQty>
    </InventoryBalanceData>
</GetInventoryBalance>
```

In the xml file, the tag **AllocatedQty** can either be there or not. How to check if this tag exists in the file?

I have tried to use this, but to no avail:

```
<#if BODY.InventoryBalanceData.AllocatedQty?has_content>
```

Comment: That's how it's done though. So does anything return a non-empty set of nodes? Like does `${BODY.InventoryBalanceData.AvailableQty}` print `10.0000`?